# Is there a DNase that works at low temperature, and is it also commerically available?

Tags: enzymes, cell-sorting, dnase

In preparation for FACS, I need to keep mammalian neurons on ice (in PBS-- / BSA), but as they still die while waiting ~30 minutes, they release their DNA into the solution. This leads to cell clumps. Thus, I need to refilter cells on a 35 um sieve (Blue FACS tube caps) and I loose a lot of cells that get entangled in the clump (up to 2mm in diameter).

One way to avoid such clumps would be to keep the DNA chopped, so I would only lose the cells that die anyways, not the many additional ones that get entangled.

**Therefore I would need a commercially available DNase that works at low temperature (~0˚), has no RNase activity, and ideally temperature sensitive (easy to deactivate).**

I found the following leads, but none are a very good match, nor do I have any experience with any.

1. [Heat-labile (Cryophile) DNase (Thermolabile).](https://www.cambio.co.uk/2341/220/products/cryophile-dnase-(heat-labile)/)
2. [Psychrophilic DNAse](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30539415/)

   1. Problem: it is a [Non-specific nuclease](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/DNA/RNA_non-specific_endonuclease), cutting RNA
3. [Cryonase Cold-active Nuclease from Takara](https://www.takarabio.com/documents/User%20Manual/2670A/2670A_e.v1702Da.pdf)
4. [Thermolabile and Double-Strand Specific DNase](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0010295)
5. [Heat-Labile Double-Strand Specific DNase (HL-dsDNase)](https://arcticzymes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/HL-dsDNase-INT-web.pdf)